# Application_Model_Classname not found in Zend framework

Tags: sql-server, zend-framework

I am using following directory structure in Wamp server and i am getting an **error** `Fatal error: Class 'Application_Model_ClassName' not found`:

```
www--->pnp--->client--->application
                            --->controllers
                            --->modules
                            --->models      
                    --->docs
                    --->library
                    --->public
                    --->.htaccess
                    --->.buildpath
```

But when i remove **client directory** from the above structure its working fine. With the following structure its working fine.

```
www--->pnp--->application
                       --->controllers
                       --->modules
                       --->models       
          --->docs
          --->library
          --->public
          --->.htaccess
          --->.buildpath
```

Please suggest, so that i can use **client** or **dev** or **qa** directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to autoload model files in the the Bootstrap.php, with the following code.

```
protected function _initAutoLoad ()
{
    $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(
    array('basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH, 'namespace' => 'Application', 
    'resourceTypes' => array(
    'form' => array('path' => 'forms/', 'namespace' => 'Form'), 
    'model' => array('path' => 'models/', 'namespace' => 'Model'))));
    return $autoLoader;
}
```